# Postgresql \COPY command and quote-less file

Tags: postgresql, csv

Is there anyway to disable `QUOTE AS` this data distributor is giving out a file that has a set up like,

```
col1,col2
foo,bar
```

Some columns are a little more complex

```
col1,col2
Test outside-"bar' Blah blah` Someone else,What
```

Now the question: Is there a better way than giving `QUOTE AS` a character that is assumed not to exist?

```
\COPY maxmind.country FROM worldcitiespop.txt CSV QUOTE AS '$' HEADER
```

Where `$` is an assumption the character doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know that the quote character doesn't exist, csv formats can escape quotes if necessary. You should just pick the appropriate dialect for what worldcitiespop.txt contains.

Comment: There is no quote character though, it's just comma separated, i.e., commas can not occur in the data all possible quote characters can.